# Is spam filtering on-device possible on the new iPad?

Tags: ipad, email

Is there any way to enable spam filtering on iPad mail?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. The filtering happens on your mail server, if the one that you are using supports spam filter (like Gmail).